# How can I modify `gem kaminari` pagination links?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, kaminari

I'm doing a Rails application with `gem 'kaminari'`.

**Like in the given screenshot below**,

all `links` in `generated pagination` starts with 
`localhost:5000`

but i need to modify it and change,

`localhost:5000` to something like => `https://new_domain` and the rest of the url to follow....

Or set the **HOST** like in `default_url_options`.

Please help!

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to change the host of the links? Kaminari uses the hostname the current environment is running on – what seems to be localhost in your development environment. This seems like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want customize look in kaminari first generate pages which kaminari. Run below generator

```
 rails g kaminari:views default
```

then edit the partials in your app's app/views/kaminari/ directory.

Comment: yes i tried that, but my function for rendering  is in another gem. I'm looking for any other options if there is :)